# pandas : 'tzinfo' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe is resulting from postgres databases. The dynamic_col changes of type from table to other. I want to drop the zone, so i wrote the rows below, but im gotting this error

```
E   TypeError: 'tzinfo' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

data:

```
 2019-09-21, 
 2012-10-09,
 None,
 2012-10-23
```

**My code is here**

```
df[str(self.dynamic_col)] = df[str(self.dynamic_col)].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=None) if isinstance(x, datetime.date) and x != 'None'  else x)
```

Comment: Who goes around downgrading questions without leaving a comment. This is wrong, we can all do better... Also, this question adheres to the guidelines of SO hence I don't see any reason to downgrade it.

Comment: Date objects don't have associated timezones. Datetimes might.

Comment: @AKX but how can i say drop the zone the column is date, ? because dynamic_col can change of type from table to other. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

As the error says, [`datetime.date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) does not take an argument `tzinfo`.

Comment: thank you, but how should i do to drop the zone if the column is datetime.date?

Comment: @biwia [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) instances don't have a time zone.

Comment: aah ok thank you, but how can i say drop the zone the column is date, ? because dynamic_col can change of type from table to other. Am i clear please?

Comment: No you are not. Please open a new question with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).